# I don't know where to start with ethernet communication with Automation Direct P1AM-200 ETH module communication

Tags: ethernet, arduino-ide, plc

I am using the P1AM-200 Automation Direct PLC and ETH module.  The P1AM uses Arduino IDE for programming. I have reviewed the example code that Arduino provides for the ethernet library, but I have so far been unable to establish 2-way communication.  I am able to set up a server on the PLC but I can only send or receive bytes over ethernet on the desktop computer that the PLC is directly connected to through over ethernet.  I also have the Serial connection always connected.  I would appreciate any help in understanding ethernet, I am not well versed. I am using a CAT6A ethernet cable.

I have tried to read the ASCII characters sent over ethernet from the PC on the PLC and that works, but when I try to send bytes back, I am unable to read them on the other end.  If I write on one end, I cant write on then other.  I have ensured that the ETH module initializes.

Comment: What TCP/UDP port(s) or protocol(s) or service(s) are you using?  It sounds like you are trying to use an Ethernet connection as a serial port (e.g. sending/receiving bytes or ASCII characters).  Make sure any routers or switches you are using pass those through.  Are all the IP settings of the critical devices on your subnet configured correctly?